# What do you call a person who chooses to ignore someone at specific periods of time

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

Imagine a person X who chooses to ignore his/her responsibilities and family at will, only to attend to them when he/she sees a tangible gain to be had out of it.

*Selfish* is one option, but I'm looking for something more specific.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You might call them a **fair-weather friend**:

> *Fair-weather friend:*
>
> Someone who stops being supportive or loyal when you run into difficulties and need help.
>
> ([The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fair-weather+friend))

Basically, a fair-weather friend is there for you when it's convenient for them, but when they'd actually have to do something for you, suddenly they disappear.

Answer (score 2):

Self-centered.  If the individual is acting out of spite, passive aggressive.

Answer (score 0):

That person is **irresponsible** and **opportunistic**.

> - opportunist - (noun) "someone who tries to get an advantage or something valuable from a situation without thinking about what is fair or right." [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/opportunist)
> - opportunistic - (adj) "exploiting opportunities with little regard to principle or consequences" [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/opportunistic)

Answer (score 0):

> ~...  " **inconsiderate**"- adj, lacking regard for the rights or feelings of others.
>   ([vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/inconsiderate))

- Most inconsiderate behavior is also selfish.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is good English or not, but I've heard the term **functional** in the form, "For Dave, friendship is functional. He'll be friendly when there's something to be gained."

Comment: Hello, Robert Grant. Please consider giving your answer more authority by citing (and, if possible, linking to) a reference work that supports using _functional_ in the relevant way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would most definitely call this person ***unreliable*** in the English Language.

> *"I was supposed to be meeting Erin for lunch, but she didn't turn up because it was her turn to pay. She's such an **unreliable** friend."*

There's also ***Capricious***, which means "Given to sudden behavior change". This could attribute to a sudden change in circumstances that lead to a friendship not being "profitable" for them anymore.